# Need to change RewriteRule for some conditions

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller, url-rewriting

I have .htaccess file with next rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?view=$1 [L,QSA]
```

URL like `mysite.com?view=catalog`  now works like`mysite.com/catalog`

But i have some conditions with `?do=value`. 

One of this conditions is LogOut funtions `mysite.com/?do=logout`. 
It's work corectly. 
But for other contitions with `?do` it's not working. 

For example `?do=extend&id=1` or `?do=delete&id=1`.
Maybe i need to change my RewriteRule to exlude `?do=value`?

**Here is the SEF URL function :**

```
function humanURL(){
     $link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB) or      die(mysqli_error($link));

     $url_parameters = array();

     $query_string = str_replace("view=","",trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']));

     $query_string = urldecode($query_string);

     $query_params = explode("/",$query_string);

     foreach ($query_params as $id =>$query_param)
        if ($query_param != "")
     $url_parameters[] = clear($query_param);

  return $url_parameters;
}
```

**Here is my SEF URL array:**

```
$url_parameters = humanURL();
$view         = $url_parameters[0];
$GET_PARAM    = $url_parameters[1];
$GET_VALUE    = $url_parameters[2];
$GET_PAGE     = $url_parameters[3];
$GET_PAGE_VAL = $url_parameters[4];
```

**Here is my including into index.php**

```
<?php if(isset($view)):?>
    <?php  include_once $view.'.php';?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php  include_once 'catalog.php';?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And this is the error message what it retuns with `?do=value&value=1` except `do=logout`

> Warning: include_once(do=extend&id=19.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory...

Than's alot for any help. If someone need more detailed info i will edit this topic

Comment: could you please add the code where you set `$view` with `$_GET['view']` ?

Comment: Someone please ^_^ help me! :)